# Using checkbox to input text

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am using Django 1.9 to work my project. I have to use checkbox to enter text. When I use text area to type in it doesn't work, but I do not know how to change it to checkbox.

> textareaform.html

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="{{ form.menwomenkids.id_for_label }}">please write "men","women" or "kids"</label>
                        {{ form.menwomenkids|add_class:"form-control" }}
                    </div>
```

It will show the form and it can work.

[image]

However, after I changed to checkbox, I do not how to do it?

> checkboxform.html

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="{{ form.menwomenkids.id_for_label }}"></label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="men" value="Men"> men<br>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="women" value="Women"> women<br>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="kids" value="Kids"> kids<br>
                    </div>
```

It will shows the checkbox form, but checked it did not enter text.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the same name attribute.

Comment: thanks , after I changed <input type="checkbox" name="men" value="Men"> men<br> ===> <input type="checkbox" name="menwomenkids" value="Men"> men<br>  it can work

Comment: and how can I make it only can check one box ?

Comment: By adding the same name to all choises ex. name="gender"

Comment: thank you,I change to type="radio" ,and it only allow one select

Answer (score 1):

Do it with django forms, add a field `forms.MultipleChoiceField`.

In choices pass your choices as a tuple eg:

```
choices = [
    ('men', 'men'),
    ('women', 'women'),
    ('kids', 'kids'),
]
```

Then just render your form in your template with

`{{ your_form.as_p }}`

check your structure.

or set name="person_type" for each input, and access it in your view with

`selected_items = request.GET.getlist("person_type")`